# Do TV news-readers ever read news about themselves?

Tags: news

(Sort of) recently, on the Irish RTE news, an item was read about a man who was being sentenced for stalking/harassing news-reader Sharon Ní Bheoláin.

However Sharon herself wasn't presenting the news that day, and the actual news-reader was free to say, "[name], who was convicted of stalking RTE news-reader Sharon Ní Bheoláin, was sentenced today..." and it got me thinking how funny it would be if she were the one reading that particular item or even at the desk while it was being read ("... who was convicted of stalking *me* was sentenced today...") and that they must have deliberately given her the day off to avoid this situation.

So my question is, is it standard procedure to give a news-reader the day off if there is an item about themselves? Has it happened on a major (national-level) news broadcast that a normally impartial news-reader has had to tell news about themselves?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because TV news, sports and current affairs are off-topic https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Luciano I used to think that _certain TV news_ were off topic. But if I understand the question correctly, it is rather about the production of TV news.

Answer (score 1):

Usually not.

Most news programmes will aim to be impartial, so reading a story about yourself cuts across that entirely.

Sometimes the BBC reports on themselves (as a corporation), but they manage to do that in the same professional manner as they would do for anything else.

But most news programmes have a team of presenters so that these personal conflicts shouldn't play out in the way you describe.